# How to remove the last index of a comma from the text file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to remove the last comma in the text file which i have opened and used.
I am using the (`String.LastIndexOf`) function to try and make this work.

However it is not working. How can i make the last comma in the text file i open deleted?

Here is what i have tried so far:

```
DialogResult openFile = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (openFile == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Functions func = new Functions();
    string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
    sfd.FileName = "New Text Doucment";
    sfd.Title = "Save As Text File";
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string path = sfd.FileName;
        StreamWriter bw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(path));
        bw.WriteLine(content);
        bw.Close();
        File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(x => string.Format("{0},", x)));
        string newContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
        newContent = newContent.Remove(newContent.LastIndexOf(","));
    }
}
```

However when i check the file to see the last comma removed, it is not working?
Am i doing something wrong or am i missing something?

Help appreciated!

Note: I am taking the original text file, reading its content and adding a comma at the end of each line. I am then writing it in the new text file but i need to get rid of the last comma since it causes issues when it is run in SQL (the file)

Comment: Question, you create the file and write "content" to it, why then would you read it all back in again, why not just work on the original content variable

Comment: Does the file contain a comma at all? If not you'll get an exception. Also, you don't remove the last comma but you remove it plus everything that comes after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't write the result back out to the file:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, newContent);
```

Just reading the text into memory and manipulating it there in your program isn't going to automatically update the file from which it was read.  That would be unexpected behavior, to say the least.

Comment: i am a complete fool, thanks for the obvious! (no sarcasm)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to, just change

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(x => string.Format("{0},", x)));
```

to

```
File.WriteAllText(path, string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, File.ReadAllLines(path)));
```

and remove the other two lines.

NOTE: The `+ Environment.NewLine` keeps the lines separated when written back to the file, adding it as suggested in comments.

Comment: This right there. The best way to "remove" the last comma is to not even add it in the first place. -- Maybe you want `"," + Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: @Corak I believe you're right, gonna amend the answer

Comment: you see the new line at the end will still keep a comma at the end of the last non empty line in the text file, which will throw an error when i run it in SQL

Comment: @someguy76 - so you have a trailing newline in the file? Can you remove that (manually)? Or maybe do something like `string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line)))`.

Comment: Forgot to switch WriteAllLines for WriteAllText, fixed

Comment: You see that line was added to ensure a comma is added to the end of each line to the original file. This does not work in my situation, ill edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You have manipulated your text only in memory and haven't wrote those changes to file.

```
DialogResult openFile = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (openFile == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Functions func = new Functions();
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
            sfd.FileName = "New Text Doucment";
            sfd.Title = "Save As Text File";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                content= content.Remove(content.LastIndexOf(","));
                string path = sfd.FileName;                    
                File.WriteAllLines(path, content.Split(','));                    
            }
        }
```

And it seems

```
Functions func = new Functions();
```

this line of code is unnecessary here.

Comment: ah yes, ive made changes when i needed it before, forgot to remove this line

Comment: Content does not have a .split available